# Annotation issue in Hateoas PHP library

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, annotations, entity, hateoas

I'm having an issue with a [Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) library for PHP.

I have a Doctrine Entity where I want add an exclusion annotation to the relation annotation as shown by an example in the [documentation](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas#exclusion) If I do this I get the following error:

> [Semantical Error] Annotation @Hateoas\Exclusion is not allowed to be
>   declared on class My\Entity\Order. You may only use this annotation
>   on these code elements: ANNOTATION

Does anybody know how to fix this? Or is it a bug or bad documentation?

The Entity:

```
<?php

namespace My\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Hateoas\Configuration\Annotation as Hateoas;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`order`")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *      "self",
 *      href = "expr('/order/' ~ object.getId())"),
 *      exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(
 *          groups = {"production"}
 *      )
 * )
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *      "self",
 *      href = "expr('/production/' ~ object.getId())"),
 *      exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(
 *          groups = {"order"}
 *      )
 * )
 */
class Order
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed that I closed the Relation annotation to early.

Updated entity:

```
<?php

namespace My\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Hateoas\Configuration\Annotation as Hateoas;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`order`")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *      "self",
 *      href = "expr('/order/' ~ object.getId())",
 *      exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(
 *          groups = {"production"}
 *      )
 * )
 * @Hateoas\Relation(
 *      "self",
 *      href = "expr('/production/' ~ object.getId())",
 *      exclusion = @Hateoas\Exclusion(
 *          groups = {"order"}
 *      )
 * )
 */
class Order
{

}
```

Comment: Does it fix your issue?